# /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

Tags: database, wp-config

I'm using Wordpress v.3.4.2 and today I've tried to update to the v.3.7.1 using all possible ways but in all of them I got the following error "Can't estabilish database connection", and since I was using the configuration below in my wp-config.php for the current version (3.4.2) why it is not working in the new one (3.7.1)? Could someone please help me? See wp-config.php database info:

```
define('DB_NAME', 'wp_blog');
define('DB_USER', 'user');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'pass');
define('DB_HOST', '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock');
```

Comment: Please provide [debugging information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress).  Also, can you go to `yoursite.com/wp-admin/` ?  Sometimes that will provide more information than `Can't establish database connection.`

Comment: Is the database server running? Have you tried using `localhost` or your server's IP address instead of the filesystem path (which I have never seen used before-- interesting though)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why lately ppl define the path to their DB_HOST like you do.
*(Assuming it is a way server is configurated (or using a MAC) and/or as pseudo layer of security?)*

Anyway, you will have your reason for it, maybe one of these codelines below could help you.

```
define('DB_HOST', ':/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock');
```

I could be wrong but the colon is important with this so try it out.

```
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost:/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock');
```

Assuming the path is correct you show us.
or maybe some like this?:

```
define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1:10000');
define('DB_PORT', 10000);
```

Check if it is the correct port else change it into the right portnumber.

Last but not least:

```
define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');
```

And like others also may ask, why not using localhost as 90% would/can do?
Hope it helps you to the right direction because this is all I can offer.

*note*
Not sure if it will show you anything but maybe try following to add in your wp-config.php also.

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true ); // set to false to disable all below
if ( WP_DEBUG ) {
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true ); // writes errors down in wp-content/debug.log
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true ); // throws error output on screen, set to false to disable screen output
@ini_set('display_errors',1); // set to zero to disable displaying it and only writing to logfile
define('SAVEQUERIES', true); // could have heavy perfomance impact, set to false if not needed!
}
```